# Error While reading the CSV in Jupyter Notebook via Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I am new to python and pandas, i am trying to import a structured csv file in jupyter notebook by using conventional code .i.e

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Datasets/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data")
df.head(5)
```

but every time i am getting the below error, please help me since i am supposed to submit my assignment

````
<ipython-input-11-33127abc1814> in <module>
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 df=pd.read_csv("Datasets/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data")
      3 df.head(5)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, skipfooter, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, cache_dates, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, doublequote, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, delim_whitespace, low_memory, memory_map, float_precision)
    683         )
    684 
--> 685         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    686 
    687     parser_f.__name__ = name

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    455 
    456     # Create the parser.
--> 457     parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
    458 
    459     if chunksize or iterator:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, f, engine, **kwds)
    893             self.options["has_index_names"] = kwds["has_index_names"]
    894 
--> 895         self._make_engine(self.engine)
    896 
    897     def close(self):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _make_engine(self, engine)
   1133     def _make_engine(self, engine="c"):enter code here
   1134         if engine == "c":
-> 1135             self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
   1136         else:
   1137             if engine == "python":

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in __init__(self, src, **kwds)
   1915         kwds["usecols"] = self.usecols
   1916 
-> 1917         self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
   1918         self.unnamed_cols = self._reader.unnamed_cols
   1919 

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__()

pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source()

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File b'Datasets/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data' does not exist: b'Datasets/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data'```
````

Comment: the error says it all, the file does not exist. Provide the absolute path to the file `C:/path/to/file.csv`?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you just need to add `.csv` in the filename. So, please try:

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_csv("Datasets/Border_Crossing_Entry_Data.csv")
df.head(5)
```